# How to call the CLLocation Manager delegate methods in iOS7 using swift

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I am working with swift 2.2 and have created an app that sends the location to a mdm server . I have declared the class as a subClass of NSObject and have included the CLLOcationManagerDelegate. But the methods like didUpdateLocations() and didUpdateToLocation() aren't getting called . I am not using any of the buttons or anything in the view that sends the location . I want the app to send the location to the server when the app updates location. Here's my code.

```
class LocationProcessHandler: NSObject , CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    var location = CLLocationManager()
    func startLocationUpdates() {



        NSLog("It entered the start location updates method of the location process handler")
    if (!(CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) || (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied )) {

        NSLog("It Entered to create the managed app feedback ")
        let persist = Persistence()

                    let json: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
            "IsLocationSettingsEnabled" : "\(0)",mdmiosagent_Constants.MESSAGETYPEKEY : mdmiosagent_Constants.LOCATIONMSGTYPEKEY,mdmiosagent_Constants.UDIDKEY : persist.getObject(mdmiosagent_Constants.UDIDKEY),"TimeStamp" : "\(self.toLocalTime())"
        ]
        let userDefaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        userDefaults.setObject(json, forKey: mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APP_FEEDBACK)
        userDefaults.synchronize()
        NSLog("The dict to be sent as managed app feedback is \(json)")
        do {
        let jsonData : NSData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
            let wrapper = HttpWrapper()
            wrapper.silentPostData(serverurl: mdmiosagent_Constants.NATIVE_APP_SERVLET, urldata: jsonData)
        } catch {
            NSLog("json error")
        }

}
    location.delegate = self
    location.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters


            if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
                location.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            }
        location.delegate = self
        location.startUpdatingLocation()
        NSLog("Started to monitor the significant location Changes")
    location.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    location.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

    }

func location(manager: CLLocationManager!,
                     didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    var shouldIAllow = false
    var locationStatus = String()
    switch status {
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
        locationStatus = "Restricted Access to location"
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
        locationStatus = "User denied access to location"
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
        locationStatus = "Status not determined"
    default:
        locationStatus = "Allowed to location Access"
        shouldIAllow = true
    }
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("LabelHasbeenUpdated", object: nil)
    if (shouldIAllow == true) {
        NSLog("Location to Allowed")
        // Start location services
        location.startUpdatingLocation()
    } else {
        NSLog("Denied access: \(locationStatus)")
    }
}

func processMessage (dict : NSDictionary) {
    let msgType : NSString = dict.objectForKey(mdmiosagent_Constants.MESSAGETYPEKEY) as! String
    if (msgType.isEqual(mdmiosagent_Constants.MONITORREGIONKEY)) {
       // self.startmonitoring(dict)
    }
}

func stopLocationUpdates() {
    location.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    location.stopUpdatingLocation()

}
// this particular function is Used with two commands but not used as of now
func startmonitoring (currentLocation : CLLocation) {
    let latitude : Double = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
    let Longitude : Double = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
    let regionID = "GeoFenceTrack"
    let region: CLCircularRegion = CLCircularRegion.init(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, Longitude), radius: Double(mdmiosagent_Constants.LOCATIONRADIUS)! , identifier: regionID)
    location.delegate = self
    location.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    location.stopMonitoringForRegion(region)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    NSLog("Location Updated")
    let persist = Persistence()
    let currentLocation : CLLocation = locations[0]
    let latitude : Double = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
    let Longitude : Double = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
    let regionID = "GeoFenceTrack"
    let region : CLCircularRegion = CLCircularRegion.init(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, Longitude), radius: Double(persist.getObject(mdmiosagent_Constants.LOCATIONRADIUS))!, identifier: regionID)
    self.sendLocation(currentLocation)
    location.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    location.delegate = self
    location.stopMonitoringForRegion(region)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {
    NSLog("Location Updated")

    let latitude : Double = newLocation.coordinate.latitude
    let Longitude : Double = newLocation.coordinate.longitude

    let regionID = "GeoFenceTrack"
    let region : CLCircularRegion = CLCircularRegion.init(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, Longitude), radius: Double(mdmiosagent_Constants.LOCATIONRADIUS)!, identifier: regionID)
     location.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
    let currentLocation = newLocation
    self.sendLocation(currentLocation)
}

func sendLocation ( currentLocation : CLLocation ) {
    let latitude: String = "\(Int(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude))"
    let longitude : String = "\(Int(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude))"

    let json: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
        mdmiosagent_Constants.MESSAGETYPEKEY : mdmiosagent_Constants.LOCATIONMSGTYPEKEY,
        mdmiosagent_Constants.LATITUDEKEY : latitude,
        mdmiosagent_Constants.LONGITUDEKEY : longitude,
        mdmiosagent_Constants.UDIDKEY : defaults.UDID,
        "TimeStamp" : "\(self.toLocalTime())",
        "IsLocationSettingsEnabled" : "\(CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())"
    ]

    let userDefaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    userDefaults.setObject(json, forKey: mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APP_FEEDBACK)
    userDefaults.synchronize()
    do {
        let jsonData : NSData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        let wrapper = HttpWrapper()
        wrapper.silentPostData(serverurl: mdmiosagent_Constants.NATIVE_APP_SERVLET, urldata: jsonData)
    } catch {
        NSLog("json error")
    }
```

Comment: Can you specify your question and those two methods. Yours two methods didn't work in iOS7? For I know there are no deprecated functions between iOS7 and iOS8 in the CLLocationManagerDelegate
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/

Comment: I have to use requestWhenInuseAuthorization() and requestAlwaysAuthorization() right to make the delegate methods to be called ? These two methods are deprecated right

Comment: You don't need to call these two functions before iOS8, so your question is when you call these functions your app will crash?

Comment: No , didUpdateLocations and didUpdateToLocation methods are not getting called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in iOS 7 and above you can use the following methods

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!){
    print("latitude：\(manager.location.coordinate.latitude)")
    print("longitude：\(manager.location.coordinate.longitude)")
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,didFailWithError error: NSError!){
    print("error")
}
```

ensure once your class confirm

```
 import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController , CLLocationManagerDelegate{
```

chcek like on call

```
  self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  let Device = UIDevice.currentDevice()
 private let iosVersion = Double(Device.systemVersion) ?? 0 
if iosVersion >= 8 {
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}
self.locationManager.delegate = self
self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

**update**

add this and check once the status is already granted or not

```
  // authorization status
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        var shouldIAllow = false

        switch status {
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
            locationStatus = "Restricted Access to location"
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
            locationStatus = "User denied access to location"
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
            locationStatus = "Status not determined"
        default:
            locationStatus = "Allowed to location Access"
            shouldIAllow = true
        }
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("LabelHasbeenUpdated", object: nil)
        if (shouldIAllow == true) {
            NSLog("Location to Allowed")
            // Start location services
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
            NSLog("Denied access: \(locationStatus)")
        }
}
```

Comment: Can I use it as such without calling requestWhenInuseAuthorization() and requestAlwaysAuthorization() ?

Comment: Its not a subClass of UIViewController , Is that is what is preventing the methods to be called ?

Comment: if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
                    location.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                }
            location.delegate = self
            location.startUpdatingLocation()

Comment: I have to add that part of the code like this , Is this the right way to do it ?

Comment: I tried , but still program doesn't enter the didUpdatelocations method

Comment: I tried , but no changes.. i had earlier declared this class as a sub class of NSObject . May  be because of that , the location delegate methods aren't called ?

Comment: in this place `if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {`, use my code

Comment: well , my code is working , but now , it's like the alert in which the user can allow the location access keeps popping up and disappears, then again pops up .. Any idea why ? As far as i studied , i should have a strong reference to CLLocationManager

Comment: @ManeeshSharma - happy to hearbro, where u called this method startLocationUpdates

Comment: in appDelegate .. like this

Comment: if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] != nil {
        
            let app : UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
            var bgTask : UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
            bgTask = app.beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({ () -> Void in
                app.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
            })
            self.startLocationUpdates()
            }

Comment: i think ur method called at twice

Comment: once in viewDidLoad & ViewDidAppear

Comment: called in any one place its better called in only on `viewDidLoad` is fine. congratz and do well

Comment: Sorry , its in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and viewDidBeccomeActive

Comment: @ManeeshSharma - haha aha, then called in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` only bro, it is enough, ok if my answer is useful plz aaccept